# How to set up LSP for Emacs with Julia

Tags: emacs, julia

I would like to use Julia with Emacs and have installed `julia-mode`, `julia-repl` and `lsp-julia`. I am using Julia 1.7.3.

I have added the following to my `init.el`

```lisp
(require 'lsp-mode)
(add-hook 'julia-mode-hook #'lsp)
(require 'lsp-ui)
(require 'julia-mode)
(require 'julia-repl)
(require 'lsp-julia)
(julia-repl-set-terminal-backend 'vterm)
(add-hook 'julia-mode-hook 'julia-repl-mode) ;; Always use minor mode
(require 'vterm)
```

However, when I have the `(add-hook 'julia-mode-hook #'lsp)` line enabled the keyboard shortcuts don't work (e.g., C-Enter is not found). All I want to do is set up julia in Emacs in a similar way using LSP with keyboard shortcuts to how I have it in VSCode.

What have I done wrong in my `init.el`?

Comment: What do you mean the keyboard shortcuts don't work? The `lsp-mode` doesn't ensure it have the same shortcuts with in VSCode. You have to set it by yourself.

Comment: I don't want it to have the same shortcuts as VSCode, but I can no use my Emacs keyboard shortcuts (e.g. C-Enter to send code to the REPL) when I have lsp-mode enabled in my init.el file.

Comment: Press `C-h k C-Enter` and see what you have run.